# Is there a way to optimize/vectorize these loops over elements in a 3D array, without requiring significantly more memory?

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization, memory, vectorization

I am looking for some help to speed up some Matlab code.

A minimal example is shown below. The code is doing some calculations on a 3D matrix, defined on [x,y,z] coordinates. When using the profiler, the inner loop over `ind` is the time-consuming part, and so I am wondering if this loop can either be optimized, or removed/vectorized completely.

```matlab
Nx = 8; % Number of grid points
Ny = 6;
Nz = 4;
Ntot = Nx*Ny*Nz;

xvals = rand(1,Nx); % Create grid vectors
yvals = rand(1,Ny);
zvals = rand(1,Nz);

input_vec = rand(Ny,Nx,Nz); % Generate a dummy 3D matrix ( meshgrid convention, [y,x,z] )
input_vec = reshape( permute(input_vec,[3,1,2]) , [Ntot 1]); % Unwrap to 1D, so z cycles fastest, then y, then x

C1 = 5; % Loop counters
C2 = 6;
C3 = 7;

output_vec = zeros(Ntot,1); % Preallocate
temp_vec = zeros(Ntot,1);

for cnt1 = 1:C1
    for cnt2 = 1:C2
        for cnt3 = 1:C3
            
            factor1 = xvals*cnt1; % Calculate some vectors which depend on cnt variables
            factor2 = yvals*cnt2;
            factor3 = zvals*cnt3;
            
            for ind = 1:Ntot % Loop over every grid point
                j1 = floor( floor((ind-1) / Nz) / Ny) + 1; % +1 and -1 's account for Matlab's [1] indexing
                j2 = mod( floor((ind-1)/Nz) , Ny ) + 1;
                j3 = mod( (ind-1), Nz ) + 1;
                temp_vec(ind) = input_vec(ind) * factor1(j1)*factor2(j2)*factor3(j3);
            end
            output_vec = output_vec + temp_vec;
        end
    end
end
```

In my real application, the number of points is more like 1024x1024x512, and so I have tried to avoid using lots of `meshgrid` formatted variables (which contain a lot of repeated information) in order to keep the memory requirements down - this is the reason that the 3D array has been unwrapped to 1D in the code above. For example, one solution might be to precalculate all the `j1,j2,j3` values like so

```matlab
j1 = 1:Nx;
j2 = 1:Ny;
j3 = 1:Nz;
[J1,J2,J3] = meshgrid(j1,j2,j3);
J1 = reshape( permute(J1,[3,1,2]) , [Ntot 1]); % Unwrap to 1D, so z cycles fastest, then y, then x 
J2 = reshape( permute(J2,[3,1,2]) , [Ntot 1]); 
J3 = reshape( permute(J3,[3,1,2]) , [Ntot 1]);
```

but this requires much more RAM than calculating a single value of j each time depending on the value of ind.

Can anyone help with a better/faster (but still memory efficient) way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Funny, Steve just posted on his blog ["Use less meshgrid and repmat"](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2021/07/26/use-less-meshgrid-and-repmat/). That might give you an idea on how to simplify that code to compute `J1`, `J2` and `J3` without using `meshgrid`. `permute` on a multi-dimensional array is expensive (requires a copy), it's easier to reorder the inputs and outputs to `meshgrid`. But you don't need `meshgrid` to start with anyway.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Interesting. Thanks for pointing me to that. I was aware of that kind of thing in principle. There is also a file here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74956-ndgridvecs which makes use of expansion to do what looks like somthing similar. Unfortunately, I can't even see where to start at applying it to my problem though! Can you provide any example to show how to go about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```matlab
factor1 = xvals*cnt1; % Calculate some vectors which depend on cnt variables
factor2 = yvals*cnt2;
factor3 = zvals*cnt3;
for ind = 1:Ntot % Loop over every grid point
   j1 = floor( floor((ind-1) / Nz) / Ny) + 1; % +1 and -1 's account for Matlab's [1] indexing
   j2 = mod( floor((ind-1)/Nz) , Ny ) + 1;
   j3 = mod( (ind-1), Nz ) + 1;
   temp_vec(ind) = input_vec(ind) * factor1(j1)*factor2(j2)*factor3(j3);
end
```

can be written as (not tested):

```matlab
factor1 = xvals*cnt1; % Calculate some vectors which depend on cnt variables
factor2 = yvals*cnt2;
factor3 = zvals*cnt3;
ind = 1:Ntot;
j1 = floor( floor((ind-1) / Nz) / Ny) + 1; % +1 and -1 's account for Matlab's [1] indexing
j2 = mod( floor((ind-1)/Nz) , Ny ) + 1;
j3 = mod( (ind-1), Nz ) + 1;
temp_vec = input_vec(:).' .* factor1(j1).*factor2(j2).*factor3(j3);
```

(Especially not indexing with `ind` could make a big difference, though I think this is a special case that has been optimized in recent version of MATLAB.)

But there we're still creating large intermediate arrays. You should be able to simplify with (again, not tested, and likely buggy):

```matlab
factor1 = xvals*cnt1;                  % horizontal array
factor2 = (yvals*cnt2).';              % vertical array
factor3 = permute(zvals*cnt3,[1,3,2]); % array along 3rd dimension
temp_vec = input_vec .* factor1 .* factor2 .* factor3;
```

Comment: Maybe wishful thinking, but can you see any possibilty that something could be done with the C1,C2,C3 loops? Or are those ones likely unavoidable without more major changes? Thanks for your help Cris!

Comment: @teeeeee Make sure you compare the results, I might have misunderstood what your code does. I wrote this answer rather quickly while I had some code compiling here. Looking at the other loops, I think I see `out = sum_{c1,c2,c3} in * f1*c1 * f2*c2 * f3*c3`, which can be simplified as `out = in * f1 * f2 * f3 * sum_{c1,c2,c3} c1 * c2 * c3`. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: Possibly - although to be honest I am not sure I fully understand your notation. It is certainly a sum over vector indices, as I think you have indicated. In case it helps, the code is actually to calculate Eq. 42a - 42d in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301848410_A_tractable_prescription_for_large-scale_free_flight_expansion_of_wavefunctions

Comment: (the answer with expansion notation does indeed work by the way - I have compared both methods and they are equivalent).

Comment: @teeeeee Sorry, I don't at all see the relationship between equations 42a-d and your code. I assume you simplified your code a lot to post it here, so optimizing it in the way I suggested above will not translate to your actual code. But my observation was that you can move the multiplication with `input_vec`, `xvals`, `yvals` and `zvals` outside the loops, turning the loops `cnt1`-`cnt3` into something trivial you can probably pre-compute. But I don't see the same opportunity in equations 42a-d.

Comment: Hi Cris, sorry you are right, it's not easy to see from my snippet, and it has indeed been simplified above. Here is the actual code if it's helpful, where I have commented exactly which lines correspond to which equations: https://github.com/tjb36/Free_Flight_Transformer . Lines 103 and 105 have now been vectorized as you showed in your answer (they used to be loops). You can see that there are next some FFTs in there, as well as a final loop which I don't know how to vectorize. Could this make it difficult to remove the main loops, or do you still see scope for improvement? Thanks so much!