# Can this loop containing different indices be vectorized or speeded up?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have a code which is doing some processing over every point in a 3D matrix. The array `input_vec_1D` is accessed by an unusual index `ind_prime` which depends on the loop variable (for context, the index is determined from an algorithm that I am using in Eq. 42e of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301848410_A_tractable_prescription_for_large-scale_free_flight_expansion_of_wavefunctions), and my full code is [here](https://github.com/tjb36/Free_Flight_Transformer)). I have managed to get it working correctly by first turning the matrix to a 1D array, calculating the correct indices, doing the processing, and reshaping back to 3D afterwards:

```matlab
Nx = 8; Ny = 6; Nz = 4; Ntot = Nx*Ny*Nz;                    % Number of points
xvals = rand(1,Nx); yvals = rand(1,Ny); zvals = rand(1,Nz); % Grid vectors

input_vec_3D = rand(Ny,Nx,Nz); % Dummy 3D array

factor1 = 3.6*xvals; % some constant times xvals
factor2 = 1.2*yvals;
factor3 = 8.5*zvals;

input_vec_1D = reshape( permute(input_vec_3D,[3,1,2]) , [Ntot 1]); % Reshape to 1D for loop
output_vec = zeros(Ntot,1);
for ind = 1:Ntot
    j1 = floor( floor( (ind-1)/Nz ) /Ny ) + 1;   
    j2 = mod( floor( (ind-1)/Nz ) , Ny ) + 1; 
    j3 = mod( (ind-1) , Nz ) + 1;
    n1 = mod( 5*(j1-1) ,Nx);
    n2 = mod( 3*(j2-1) ,Ny);
    n3 = mod( 2*(j3-1) ,Nz);
    ind_prime = mod( ( n3 + Nz*(n2 + Ny*n1) ) , Ntot ) + 1; % a different index for input_vec
    output_vec(ind) = output_vec(ind) + input_vec_1D(ind_prime) * factor1(j1)*factor2(j2)*factor3(j3);
end
output_vec = permute( reshape( output_vec, [Nz,Ny,Nx] ) , [2,3,1] );  % Reshape back to 3D
```

This loop over all elements is the slowest part of my code, so I would like to speed it up - by vectorizing or otherwise.

My arrays are typically 512x512x1024 complex doubles, so it is crucial for my application that I did not store any temporary extra large matrices due to limited RAM (around 6 GB), which precludes the use of `meshgrid()` to generate the factors (notice that `factor1`, `factor2`, `factor3` are only 1D vectors, so memory usage for them is small).

I was kindly helped with a very similar loop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68551313/12921500), which was solved using Matlab's implicit expansion in that case. However, this is more complicated, because in the processing line different indices are used `ind_prime`, `ind`, and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorise this entirely, which will be quicker (about 50% by my tests of 512x512x10 input matrix). But that involves the creation of several arrays, which we can reduce the size of in two ways

1. Use an integer data type (e.g. `uint32`) for the indicies. `uint32` is 4 bytes per index, compared to 8 bytes for a double so that's a decent saving, especially when indices are always integers anyway. Note to make the most of this you have to use `idivide` instead of `./` to avoid MATLAB converting to double internally, and you have to convert `Nx`/`Ny`/`Nz` to `uint32` for the same reason.

   We can't use `uint8` or `uint16` as their max values are too small to cater to your large arrays.

   Also note that (by default) `idivide` uses `fix` rounding, i.e. rounding towards 0, so you can skip using `floor` and maybe make up a small amount of performance there.
2. Recycle your arrays. Instead of using `j1..3` and `n1..3`, as 6 indexing arrays, we can just reorder the operations slightly and recycle `j1..3`.

This comes together like so:

```
IND = uint32(1:Ntot); % Shorthand, could skip defining this and write each tiem if memory was tight
Nx = uint32(Nx); Ny = uint32(Ny); Nz = uint32(Nz); Ntot = Nx*Ny*Nz; % uint8 conversion
J1 = idivide( idivide(IND-1,Nz), Ny ) + 1; % idivide to avoid "double" casting, does "fix" rounding
J2 = mod( idivide( IND-1, Nz ), Ny ) + 1;  % idivide to avoid "double" casting, does "fix" rounding
J3 = mod( IND-1, Nz ) + 1;
FAC = (factor1(J1).*factor2(J2).*factor3(J3)).'; % done here so we can recycle J1..3
J1 = mod( 5*(J1-1), Nx );
J2 = mod( 3*(J2-1), Ny );
J3 = mod( 2*(J3-1), Nz );
ind_prime2 = (mod( ( J3 + Nz*(J2 + Ny*J1) ) , Ntot ) + 1).';
output_vec3 = input_vec_1D(ind_prime2) .* FAC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I can see, you have introduced x4 new arrays (IND, J1,J2,J3), which are all 1 x Ntot long. Even with 32 bit ints, this uses an additional 4.3GB for a 512 x 512 x 1024 grid. On top of that, we now have FAC which is a double type, using 2.15 GB. This is then 6.45 GB in those indexing arrays alone, right? Or do I calculate wrong?

Comment: You could do all of the maths inline, i.e. don't define any variables and have one large and ugly command - since it's now essentially a single operation. That would remove a lot of that, although your readability will be in the toilet and I'm not sure how MATLAB will handle memory as the calculation progresses. Make sure to use lots of line continuation `...` to break up your code if you choose this approach, you will also lose some performance as you'd have to calculate the `j1..3` twice (once for `FAC` and once for `n1..3`).

Comment: You could also do this in chunks of up to 255 elements and use `uint8` which is only one byte per index, but it will be a compromise on performance as it's closer to the original loop

Comment: Thanks, both good suggestions. I see a similar factor of x2 speedup, like you do. I have implemented your suggestions in my script on line 124 https://github.com/tjb36/Free_Flight_Transformer/blob/main/free_flight.m You can see that I have rearranged slightly so that I don't need FAC at all, by using implicit expansion. However, I am having to convert back from 3D to 1D array in order to use your ind_prime2, and then back to 3D afterwards. Can you see a way to do this indexing only with the 3D arrays (or any other obvious way to speed it up that jumps out at you)? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Hi Wolfie - do you have any idea on this - I am still trying to find a nice solution... thank you for your support :)